# Auto deduction of non-type template char parameters from a string in c++11

Tags: c++11, templates, non-type-template-parameter

Let's say we have the following structure defined

```
template <char T, char S>
struct chars_trait {}
```

Moreover, we have a bunch of two-char strings, for instance

```
const std::string ab = "ab";
const std::string cd = "cd";
const std::string ef = "ef";
```

My goal is to create chars_trait object for each of those strings, so

```
ab -> chars_trait<'a','b'>{}
cd -> chars_trait<'c','d'>{}
ef -> chars_trait<'e','f'>{}
```

and use them, for instance, like this

```
std::for_each(vecOfStrs.begin(), vecOfStrs.end(),
              [&](const std::string& str){doSthWithCharsTrait(getCharTrait(str));});
```

I have tried to employ a map but got stuck with two problems - first that this approach is possible from c++14, and second, much more significant - it does not work. So my question is - can I somehow improve my code? Or there is no chance of making it as I proposed?

All code here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

const std::string ab = "ab";
const std::string cd = "cd";
const std::string ef = "ef";

template <char T, char S>
struct chars_trait {};

template <char T, char S>
std::map<std::string, chars_trait<T, S>> MAPPER
{
    {ab, chars_trait<'a', 'b'>{}},
    {cd, chars_trait<'c', 'd'>{}},
    {ef, chars_trait<'e', 'f'>{}}  
};

template <char T, char S>
void print(const chars_trait<T, S>&)
{
    std::cout << T << S << std::endl;
}

void print(const std::string& str)
{
    print(MAPPER.at(str));
}


int main()
{
    print(ab);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the underlying and actual problem you try to solve? Why would something like this solve it? Please [edit] your question to ask about the actual problem directly instead, otherwise your question is just another [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: `template <char T, char S> std::map<std::string, chars_trait<T, S>>`  - this will create a map for _one_ `char_trait` based type. Not all three. A `char_trait<'a','b'>` doesn't have any relation to a `char_trait<'c','d'>` etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you're right. So how can I create an object which returns chars_trait for given string?

Comment: You could use a `std::variant` or `std::any` (or the `boost` versions of those).

Comment: Those are available from c++ 17, so I need to try boost, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than templates and Boost, you can define some simple translation functions to uint16_t, starting with these:

```
constexpr uint16_t Chars2Int(char a, char b);
constexpr std::array<char, 2> Int2Chars(uint16_t enc);
```

Then you'll have a plain integer you can use in `switch` statements, easily store in vectors, etc.

Comment: Yeah, but it introduces additional abstraction which I would like to avoid

Comment: @NiklasMan: Can you describe more precisely what you mean by "additional abstraction"?

Comment: The solution you have proposed is based on the idea of "encryption" and "decryption" pair of characters, so this is what I meant by saying "additional abstraction".

Comment: If you don't like the uint16_t encoding, just use a `struct Chars { char a, b; }`.  Simple.  Templates aren't helping you.

Comment: Your comment got cut off, but yes you should edit your question.  Pretty clearly this is an "XY problem."

Comment: Thanks for your response. Maybe I should to include it in my question - basically, I need those chars_trait
to do some stuff depending on char T and char S values. To give you some example

 struct DoSomething
 {
   template <char T, char S>
   void operator()(const chars_trait<A, B>&);
 }

 template<>
 void DoSomething::operator()<'a', 'b'>(const char_traits<'a', 'b'>& data) { ... }

 template<>
 void DoSomething::operator()<'a', 'c'>(const char_traits<'a', 'c'>& data) { ... }

Comment: All seems a bit overwrought to me, but of course I can't see your overall system architecture.

Comment: Sure. Thank you @John Zwinck for your responses.